# Is there a way to find a maximum of a function of 2 variables in Matlab using max() function?

Tags: matlab, optimization

Is there a way to find a maximum of a function of 2 variables in Matlab using ‍the `max()` function?  For example for `z = x^2 +cos(y^2)` that `x` and `y` are bounded in `[1,10]`.

Comment: It's an optimization task. So, you can't use `max` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently it is an optimization problem and a proper tool is to use `fmincon` or `fminbnd`, rather than `max`. In what follows, I listed the approaches of `fmincon`, `fminbnd` and `max`

- `fmincon` approach

```
A = [];
b = [];
x0 = [5;5];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb = [1;1];
ub = [10;10];
non = [];
[u,fval] = fmincon(@(u) -(u(1).^2 + cos(u(2).^2)),[1;1],A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,non);
Zmax = -fval;
```

which gives

```
>> Zmax
Zmax =  100.54 % seems not exactly the maximum
```

- `fminbnd` approach: since your objective function can be decomposed into two sub-optimization problems (`x` and `y` are independent), you are able to use `fminbnd` on two component terms, separately, i.e.,

```
x = fminbnd(@(x) -x.^2,1,10);
y = fminbnd(@(y) -cos(y.^2),1,10);
Zmax = x^2 + cos(y^2);
```

which gives

```
>> Zmax
Zmax =  101.00
```

- If you insist on using `max`, maybe you can try a brute-force approach like below

```
x = linspace(1,10,5e3);
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = @(x,y) x.^2 + cos(y.^2);
Zmax = max(max(z(X,Y)));
```

which gives

```
>> Zmax
Zmax =  101.00
```

Comment: @Michael if you use the method `max`, you can use `[row,col] = find(z == Zmax)` to find the indices of `Zmax` in `z`

Comment: Operator '==' is not supported for operands of type 'function_handle'.

Comment: @Michael sorry, it was my typo. it should be `[row,col] = find(z(X,Y) == Zmax)`, or you can use `Z = z(X,Y)`, then you can apply `[row,col] = find(Z == Zmax)`

Comment: It shows row and col, not values of x and y, doesn't it?

Comment: @Michael then you can use `X(row,col)` and `Y(row,col)` to retrieve the values of `x` and `y`

Comment: @Michael could you make a new post for your new question? it would be easier for others to see it as well

Answer (score 5):

It's an optimization task over a bound. So, you can use [`fminsearchbnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon) function:

```
f = @(x)(x(1)^2 + cos(x(2)^2));
g = @(x)-f(x);
x = fminsearchbnd(g,[1,1],[10,10],[]);
```